# Listing and delisting Bloomberg information in Excel

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I need to pull the IPO price for an equity security as well as buyout/delisting price for the security and the announcement date of the buyout/delisting in Excel.

I have been able to pull the IPO date using a previously mentioned function =BDP("YELP US EQUITY" "EQY_INIT_PO_DT"), so hoping something like =BDP("YELP US EQUITY", "EQY_INIT_PO_PX") will work for the IPO price. I am not sure what to try for the buyout/delisting price & announcement date. Hopefully this is a basic query, I only have sporadic and limited access to a Bloomberg terminal and essentially need to have the queries ready in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you will want EQY_INIT_PO_SH_PX for the IPO share price. EQY_INIT_PO_SH_OFFER will give you the number of shares. There is a bulk field MERGERS_AND_ACQUISITIONS that may help (using the BDS function). Do you have an example of a stock that has been delisted?

Comment: Great, thank you very much, will try it. Yes, MSM SJ EQUITY bought out by Walmart for ZARc6200. The buyout was announced on 2022-08-29, with MSM delisting on 2022-11-22. So I am looking for the fields 6200 and 2022-08-29.

Comment: Hard to say if these fields work for all equities, but one candidate is DT_OF_LAST_TRADING_SUSPENSION (16-Nov-22). Then you have MARKET_STATUS (=ACQU). You can see all the information in the Terminal, but I don't know how to get it into Excel.